# Handle Null or Missing Values in FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker, xdocreport

How to distinguish the `null` values from the missing one. I'm getting the following Java error:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing
```

Objective: I'm using `TemplateExceptionHandler` to write the missing variables in red and want to generate empty text for `null` values. The exception is raised for both missing and `null` values as they are equivalent. Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the concrete needs, but generally it's somewhat deep water.

The basic stance of FreeMarker is that `null` and missing are these same for templates, because in practice those who provide the model (the template context, the variables) often aren't consistent in this regard, especially over time. Like, maybe `user.fullName` is was once `null` for some `User` objects, but in the next version there's a class like `SystemUser` that doesn't have `getFullName` at all. Or, same with `Map`-s, where once the controller had `map.put('jiraIssue', tracking.jiraIssue)`, and sometimes `tracking.jiraIssue` was `null`, but in the next version `map.put` is just not called at all in that case. So to keep templates robust, for the template language missing and `null` are the same.

What you can do is addressing this on the `ObjectWrapper` level. Instead of the default `ObjectWrapper` instance, you can set your own with `Configuration.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper)`.
You can create a `DefaultObectWrapper` instance with its `strict` property set to `true`, and that will throw `InvalidPropertyException` if you refer to an non-existent Java bean property. That you can't handle in template, so the template will fail, and you can catch the exception and report the issue. Or, you can create a custom `ObjectWrapper` implementation that just returns `null`, but adds the variable name to the set of wrong variable names, which you report after template processing.

As of just treating `null` as empty string, yet again the template language is quite opinioned, and wants you to put a `!` after the variable name to explicitly handle the situation. But you can address this on the `ObjectWrapper` level yet again, by returning `""` with your custom `ObjectWrapper` in those cases. You can also use a `TemplateExceptionHandler`, but that can't provide a default value, it can just replace the whole failing `${...}` in the output.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed guidance. Your provided solutions for handling nulls and missing values in FreeMarker templates were incredibly helpful. I decided to implement the approach of ObjectMapper extending BeansWrapper and returning an empty string for null objects. This was achieved through an alternative method using FreeMarker's configuration settings, specifically by setting the strict property to true and configuring the NullModel to return an empty string.

Comment: Here's the modified implementation:
DefaultObjectWrapper objectWrapper = (DefaultObjectWrapper) freemarkerConfiguration.getObjectWrapper();
objectWrapper.setStrict(true);
objectWrapper.setNullModel(new SimpleScalar(""));
freemarkerConfiguration.setObjectWrapper(objectWrapper);
Thank you once again for your assistance; your insights have been invaluable in resolving this issue.

Comment: @abdellahelazzam Note that setting the `nullModel` is generally not recommended, as then the operators for missing/`null` values can't be used. Also, with that you suppress typos if the values are coming from a `Map` too (as missing `Map` keys are not an error with `strict=true`).